# Proving that solution must be equilibrium for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose that you are given a first-order differential equation for which for which unique
solutions are guaranteed for the corresponding initial value problem, for every initial condition.

If the derivative of the solution of a first order differential equation, is equal to zero at
one time instant t, then the solution must be an equilibrium solution (that is, $$x(t) = C$$
for all $t$).

How does one prove this? For a differential equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = f(x,t)$$ to have guaranteed unique solutions, $f'$ must be continuous in the $xy-$plane, but how does this imply that if, at some time $t$, $f=0$, then $f=0$ for all $t$?